# First day of Year in a between statement oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a way to get the first day of the year in a where clause using a between. Everything i've tried gave me a drill error unless using current_date. But this statement only give me the loans of today. What can i replace the first Current_date to get the first day of the year instead.

I'm trying this using on Oracle Analytics Server. The @{pvStartdate} and @{pvEnddate} are variable coming from prompts.

"Loan Details"."Loan Date" BETWEEN @{pvStartdate}{current_date} AND @{pvEnddate}{current_date}

Everything i've try didn't gave me any results except drill Errors.

Comment: I don't know Oracle Analytics Server, but - see if `trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')` helps as it returns 1st of January of this year.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you've already tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your variables in functions or expressions that perform date arithmetic.

Start date:  `TRUNC({pvStartdate},'YYYY')`
End date :   `{pvStartdate}`